# Ajax .load() specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a div *(#slide2)* where I would like to load a portion of an other .php file *(content in div.side)*. Here's what I got so far :

```
function uniqueId() { return new Date().getTime() };

$(function() {  
    $("#slide2").load("content01.php?uid= .slide"+uniqueId(), function() {
        applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();
    )};
});

function applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads() {
    $('#slides').superslides({
        slide_easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        slide_speed: 800,
        pagination: true,
        hashchange: true,
        scrollabe: true
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your problem with it?

Comment: `uid= .slide` in the URL doesn't look right. You probably don't want that space there. Without seeing `content01.php`, it's hard to tell anything else.

Comment: I ended up usign :

`$(function() {  
    $("#slide2").load("content01.php?"+uniqueId()+" #slide", function() {
        applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();
    )};
});`

**NOTICE the _space_ before _#slide_

Comment: Post what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to append the selected content (#slide2) after uniqueId

UniqueId is used so that IE and other gets the newest content, and not the one that is cached.

```
function uniqueId() { return new Date().getTime() }; // So that IE gets the newest content
   $(function() { $("#slide2").load("content01.php?"+uniqueId()+" #slide", function(){
      applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();
      });

   function applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads() {
   // All the code I need to re-initialise
   }
});
```

Though it did worked fine, does is seems to be a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(function() {  
    $("#slide2").load("content01.php #slide"+uniqueId(), function() {
        applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();
    )};
});
```

Note that `"#slide"+uniqueId()` will return the id of the content you want to load

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

I ended up using this :

`
$(function() {  
    $("#slide2").load("content01.php?"+uniqueId()+" #slide", function() {
        applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();
    )};
});
`

**NOTE the space before #slide.

Comment: Why are you appending `uniqueId()` to `content01.php?`. This seems incorrect. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Hey Wolf!

Here is all the code I used:

`
function uniqueId() { return new Date().getTime() }; // So that IE gets the newest content
   $(function() {
      $("#slide2").load("content01.php?"+uniqueId()+" #slide", function(){             applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads();       });

      function applyRestOfJqueryAfterAjaxLoads() { 
         // All the code I need to re-initialise
   }
});
`

Though it did worked fine, does is seems to be a mistake to you?

Comment: Now I got it. You were attaching `uniqueId()` to avoid caching.. :) I thought that was the `uiniqueID` to identify the content to be selected from the page. That is why I specified `"#slide"+uniqueId()` will be the return id of the content. :) Anyway, happy coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks! Starting to like this site!!